# The import org.elasticsearch.transport.client cannot be resolved

Tags: java, maven, elasticsearch

I'm trying to use Elasticsearch in Java. I hava Elasticserach version 7.0.1 installed.

The following line:

```
import org.elasticsearch.transport.client.*;
```

produces the compilation error:

> The import org.elasticsearch.transport.client cannot be resolved

Even though I can see that this is the correct path in the [source code](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/client/transport/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/transport/client/PreBuiltTransportClient.java).

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="...">
  ...
  <dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
 </prpject>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the below dependency for transport client.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: It works, but I don't understand though, if I import org.elasticsearch.transport.client, then why the dependency is org.elasticsearch.client.transport? How did you know that and how I could have found its groupId and artifactId by myself?

Comment: There different type of modules like one for core functionality, another for client etc.

Comment: Yes I know that, but how can I find by myself both the groupId and artifactId of the classes I use? I don't want to post a question for each one. And besides if the class is located in org.elasticsearch.transport.client, so I would expect the groupId to be org.elasticsearch.transport and the artifactId to be client. Why is it upside down?

Comment: Go to mvnrepository.com and search.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source code , That package has just one class. It will be conventional to use the specific path instead of calling all.

You may want to twitch your import to

```
import org.elasticsearch.transport.client.PreBuiltTransportClient;
```

Your dependency in  the pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="...">
  ...
   <dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.1</version> 
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
 </project>
```

That should resolve it.

Always refer to your build repository online to be sure you are correctly defining the latest version of your dependency.